# How can I correctly assign an Array to a struct and how can I access an array that I assigned to a struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, typedef

Still new to C and currently trying to get the hang of it.

My questions are the following:

(1) How can I access later in code the array I assign into a structure?

(2) How do I solve the *assignment from incompatible pointer type* error? Or how can I assign 
    the array correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Some_Array{
  int length;
  int *array:
} Some_Array;


Some_Array structure_arr(int *array, int length_a){
  Some_Array new_arr;
  new_arr.length = length_a;
  new_arr.array = &array; // Compiler gives warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

  return new_arr;
}


int main(){

  int my_array = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8};
  int my_array_length = 5;

  Some_Array fancy_arr = structure_arr(my_array, my_array_length);

  printf("\nLength is: %d", fancy_arr.length); // works
  printf("\n First index of fancy_arr:%d", fancy_arr.array[0]); // Doesnt work

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yay for using and mentioning warnings! Too few people do this :(

Answer (score 1):

Since `array` is already a pointer to `int`, do not use the address-of operator:

`new_arr.array = &array;` should be `new_arr.array = array;`

otherwise you assign the address of the local parameter instead of the address of the passed array.

Also fix the typo:

`int *array:` should be `int *array;`

and

`int my_array = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8};` should be `int my_array[] = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8};`